# Cannot find module 'aws-cloudfront-sign' in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I want to create CloudFront signed URL using the lambda function using this code:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
var AWS = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');

export const handler = async(event) => {

    
    var signingParams = {
  keypairId: "************************************",
  privateKeyString: "****************************************",

  privateKeyPath: '/path/to/private/key',
  expireTime: 1426625464599
}

var signedUrl = AWS.getSignedUrl(
  'http://example.cloudfront.net/path/to/s3/object', 
  signingParams
);

console.log(signedUrl);
};
```

I don't know what is happening. Another question, I have 2 keys `rsa xxxxxxx.pem` & `pk xxxxxxxxx.pem`. I'm placing the rsa.pem in keypairid and pk.pem in private key string by removing `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` & `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` from the strings.

**EDIT 1**

Now I'm doing like this but I'm getting a new error

```
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer";
export const handler = async(event) => {

    
const cloudfrontDistributionDomain = "https://**********.cloudfront.net";
const s3ObjectKey = "private-content/private.jpeg";
const url = `${cloudfrontDistributionDomain}/${s3ObjectKey}`;
const privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----******-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
const keyPairId = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----***********-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
const dateLessThan = "2022-01-01"; // any Date constructor compatible

const signedUrl = getSignedUrl({
  url,
  keyPairId,
  dateLessThan,
  privateKey,
});
console.log(signedUrl); 
    
};
```

**ERROR :**

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported",
  "trace": [
    "Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported",
    "    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)",
    "    at CloudfrontSignBuilder.signData (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer/dist-cjs/sign.js:212:21)",
    "    at CloudfrontSignBuilder.signPolicy (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer/dist-cjs/sign.js:215:42)",
    "    at CloudfrontSignBuilder.createCloudfrontAttribute (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer/dist-cjs/sign.js:240:32)",
    "    at getSignedUrl (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer/dist-cjs/sign.js:27:57)",
    "    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:17:19)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1089:29)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked two questions:

> Cannot find module 'aws-cloudfront-sign' in Lambda

`aws-cloudfront-sign` is not a package that comes by default in AWS Lambda. You need to include it as a dependency. You can use [SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html) to do that.

> I'm placing the rsa.pem in keypairid and pk.pem in private key string by removing -----...

You shouldn't remove the RSA key strings from your pem files.

Comment: Please check my edit1. Please help